# No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found using Mac OSX

Tags: gtk, wireshark

Trying to install gtk+-3.7.10 in Mac OSX 10.7.5 as a Wireshark requirement.
and failing getting error:

**No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found**

I have atk installed and referenced in my PKG_CONFIG_PATH

```
checking for ATK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (atk atk-bridge-2.0) were not met:

No package 'atk-bridge-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ATK_CFLAGS
and ATK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I used
**./configure --without-atk-bridge**, but seems to be flag is no longer available per
http://osdir.com/ml/commits.gnome/2012-06/msg06188.html
I ended up doing this hack:

```
if test x$enable_x11_backend = xyes; then
   #ATK_PACKAGES="atk atk-bridge-2.0"
   ATK_PACKAGES="atk"
else
   ATK_PACKAGES="atk"
fi
```

Commenting atk-bridge-2.0, not sure what are the implications.
Question:

1. How can I install atk-bridge-2.0?
2. Is it ok to leave it like that for
   Wireshark?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Used macosx-setup.sh which took care of dependencies.